# Show that $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 {x\ln x\over (1-xy)\ln(xy)} \, dx \, dy=1-\gamma.$

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification, definite-integrals

> $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{x\ln x\over (1-xy)\ln(xy)} \, dx \, dy=1-\gamma.\tag1$$

Let $u=xy$

$$\int_0^1 {1\over y^2}\int_0^y {u\ln u -u\ln y \over (1-u)\ln(u)}dudy\tag2$$

$$\int_0^y {u\over 1-u} \, du-\ln y\int_0^y {u\over \ln u} \, du\tag3$$

$$-y-\ln(1-y)-\ln y \int_0^y {u\over \ln u} \, du\tag4$$

As for this integral

Setting $n=1$

$$f(n,u)=\int_0^y {u^n\over \ln u} \, du\tag5$$

We can remove $\ln u$ by differentiating

$${df\over dn}=\int_0^y u^n \, du = {y^{n+1}\over n+1}\tag6$$

How can I move on to the next step?

Comment: $f(n,y)=\int_{0}^{y}\frac{u^n}{\ln u}du\,$ ?

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki Exactly! That's where he lost me too!

Comment: See also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html#eqn9

Comment: You also might be interested to know that $\displaystyle\int\limits_0^1\!\!\int\limits_0^1\!\!\int\limits_0^1\frac{x\ln x}{(1-xyz)\ln(xyz)}dx\,dy\,dz=2\gamma-1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{%
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{x\ln\pars{x} \over \pars{1 - xy}\ln\pars{xy}}
\,\dd x\,\dd y} =
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y}{\pars{x/y}\ln\pars{x/y} \over
\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{x}}\,{\dd x \over y}\,\dd y
\\[3mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over \pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{x}}
\int_{x}^{1}\bracks{x\ln\pars{x}\,{1 \over y^{2}} - x\,{\ln\pars{y} \over y^{2}}}\,\dd y\,\dd x
\\[3mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over \pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{x}}\braces{%
x\ln\pars{x}\pars{-1 + {1 \over x}} - x\bracks{1 - x + \ln\pars{x} \over x}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{1 - {1 - x + \ln\pars{x} \over \pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{x}}}
\,\dd x =
1\ -\ \underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x + \ln\pars{x} \over \pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{x}}}
_{\ds{\color{#f00}{\large ?} = \color{#f00}{\large\gamma}}} 
\,\dd x =
\color{#f00}{1 - \gamma}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\large ?} & =
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x + \ln\pars{x} \over \pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x
=
-\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{x - 1}/\ln\pars{x} - 1 \over 1 - x}\,\dd x =
-\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over 1 - x}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x^{t} - 1}\,\dd t\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{t} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x\,\dd t =
\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\Psi\pars{t + 1} + \gamma}\,\dd t =
\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{2}} - \ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{1}} + \gamma =
\color{#f00}{\gamma}
\end{align}

> Note that
>   $$
> \int_{0}^{1}\pars{x^{t} - 1}\,\dd t =
> {1 \over \ln\pars{x}}\int_{0}^{1}x^{t}\ln\pars{x}\,\dd t - 1 =
> {1 \over \ln\pars{x}}\int_{0}^{1}\partiald{x^{t}}{t}\,\dd t - 1 =
> {x - 1 \over \ln\pars{x}} - 1
> $$

Comment: Well done Felix!  +1.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks. I always like a quite complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may prove first that:
$$\iint_{(0,1)^2}\frac{x^{k+1}y^k \log(x)}{\log(xy)}\,dx\,dy = -\frac{1}{k+2}+\log(k+2)-\log(k+1)\tag{1}$$
through differentiation under the integral sign or other techniques, then by summing the RHS of $(1)$ over $k\geq 0$ we get:
$$ I = \iint_{(0,1)^2}\frac{x\log x}{(1-xy)\log(xy)}\,dx\,dy = 1-\sum_{k\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\right)=1-\gamma\tag{2}$$
as wanted.

Comment: Ick. This is why we have computer algebra systems.